# Operation Overload Multiplication inside a class

Tags: c++

I am new to operation overloading. I doing a lab where I need to be able to show the Area and circumference of a circle. The user inputs the radius and the center x,y point. My problem is that I am lost in how to properly execute the operation overload on multiplication. Could some one please help me?

This is the portion of the main.cpp

```
cout << "====================================================" << endl;
   cout << "Radius is: " << circle1.setRadius << endl;
   cout << "Area is: " << circle1.setArea << endl;
   cout << "Circumference is: " << circle1.setCircumference << endl;
```

This is my circleTypeImp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "circleType.h"
#include "pointType.h"

class CircleType;

const float PI = 3.14;

void CircleType::setRadius (float r)
{
   float radius const=r;
}

void CircleType::printCircle() const
{

}

void CircleType::setArea ()
{
   return PI * radius * radius;
}

void CircleType::setCircumference ()
{
   return 2 * PI * radius;
}
```

and this is my CircleType.h

```
#ifndef CIRCLETYPE_H
#define CIRCLETYPE_H
#include "pointType.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CircleType : public PointType
{
   public:
       void setRadius(float r);
       void printCircle() const;
CircleType& operator* (const CircleType& radius);
       void setArea();
       void setCircumference();
   private:  
       float radius const;
};
#endif
```

Thank you

Comment: `operator*` should not return a reference. It should return a new instance of an object. After all, when you multiply two values together, you don't end up with a reference to one of the values. You get a new value. Also, since multiplication does not change the values being multiplied, it should be a `const` class method, in addition to taking a `const` parameter by reference.

Comment: In addition to @SamVarshavchik comment, in the context of "I am new to operation overloading.", it may be helpful to contrast the `operator *` with the `operator *=` one.

Comment: What does it mean to multiply two circles together? Also, a lot of your functions aren't being used correctly. A setter function should return nothing and set the value of a class variable, as opposed to a get function, which takes no arguments and returns the value of a variable (or some simple calculation on variables). Also when calling a function you still need the parethesis `()` even if no parameters need to be passed.

Comment: In order for us to help you further. Can you tell us what your program is supposed to do?

Comment: The program starts by requesting an x and y for the center and that is stored in pointType class. It then shows the point as (x,y). Then it asks for the radius and is stored in circleType class. Then using the radius it is suppose to calculate the area and circumference of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I could come up with to help you out, based on your clarifications.

I've pasted and edited the code you had, and added comments to it when I made changes to detail why those changes where made.

A few of the highlights:

1. When calling any function, even those without parameters, you still need the `()`.
2. Functions that return a value, should not return `void` but rather the type of the return value. (i.e. `float` in the cases below).
3. When you want to set a member variable it's customary to use `setVariableName` or something similar and when you're returning the value of a member variable (or simple operation on) you can use `getVariableName`
   so as to avoid confusion over what the function should do.
4. You should avoid `using namespace std` in header files (.h/.hpp files), so as not to force everyone using your code to also use the same namespaces.
5. `radius` shouldn't be declared `const` as you want to be able to set it's value after creating the object.
6. when using `PI` you often want the most accurate representation for your variable type. You can often find this on many systems in `cmath` as `M_PI` (`#include <cmath>`).

I haven't done really anything with the `PointType` class or the overloaded multiplication operator as 1. I have no clue what the `PointType` class looks like and the multiplication operator doesn't seem necessary.

Below is a sample program using this class to illustrate how to use the member functions.

CircleType.h

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_TYPE_H
#define CIRCLE_TYPE_H
#include "PointType.h"
#include <iostream>
// It's common practice to not put "using namespace" in a header file.
// If you do, anyone including your header file has to use it.

class CircleType : PointType {
  public:
    void setRadius(const float r);
    void printCircle() const;

    CircleType operator * (const circleType& c) const;

    float getRadius() const;
    float getArea() const;
    float getCircumference() const;
  private:
    float radius;  // Note because you want to set radius
                   // after creation of a circle object
                   // radius should not be const
}
#endif
```

CircleType.cc

```
#include "CircleType.h" // PointType.h will also be included
#include "PointType.h"  // But it's also fine to explicitly include it
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// you don't need a dummy class here, In fact that will likely cause a compiler issue

// You should probably use a more accurate value of Pi
const float PI = 3.1415927;  // Or use M_PI in "cmath" (if it's defined on your system)

void CircleType::setRadius(const float r){
  radius = r;
}

void CircleType::printCircle() const {
  // Do whatever you need to print a circle
}

// As far as I can tell, you don't actually need to overload
// multiplication to do any the tasks you mentioned.
CircleType CircleType::operator * (const CircleType& c) const {
  CircleType tmp;
  // I have no clue what multiplying two circles gives you,
  // this is the general form of the multiplication operator
  return tmp;
}

// It is customary to name a function that returns a private variable
// or the result of simpler operations on private variables with getXXX
// like the ones below -- Note the return type is not void but
// the actual type you expect.

float CircleType::getRadius() const {
  return radius;
}

float CircleType::getArea() const {
  return PI * radius * radius;
}

float CircleType::getCircumference() const {
  return 2 * PI * radius;
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "CircleType.h"
#include "PointType.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  CircleType c1;
  float tmp;

  cout << "Input radius of circle: ";
  cin >> tmp;

  c1.setRadius(tmp);

  cout << "=============================================" << endl;
  // note even for functions that take no parameters, you still need the () to call it
  cout << "Radius is: " << c1.getRadius() << endl;
  cout << "Area is: " << c1.getArea() << endl;
  cout << "Circumference is: " << c1.getCircumference() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The operation overload is needed because that is the part of the project that I am learning about.

Comment: @JessicaDuncan What is the overloaded multiplication operator, supposed to do? You can check out what happens when you multiply two circles together (in the complex plane), from the following lecture slides. http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mampsj/Circles.pdf. The result is a Limaçon -- a group of curves similar to a cardiod. I doubt this is what you want though.

Comment: What I was trying to do is the equation pi*2*r and PI*radius*radius. Radius being a part of the class. But it is not allowing this.

Comment: you wanted the overloaded operator to find the circumference (2*pi*r) and area (pi*r*r)? Or what? If so, why is there a second circle involved?

Comment: there is no second circle.